# implicit socket bind when using sendto on a UdpSocket

Tags: rust

In `C` when `sendto` is called on a `UDP socket` (unbound), it implicitly binds the socket to some port. Is this the same in `Rust` as well [`UdpSocket::send_to`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/struct.UdpSocket.html#method.send_to) ?. If it is, then this method sort of mutates the `UdpSocket` on which `send_to` is called, but `send_to` requires parameter to be of type `&self` instead of `&mut self`, which is like a contradiction.

Comment: Sometimes it is useful to think of `&self` as a _shared reference_ and `&mut self` as an _exclusive reference_ instead of the immutable/mutable thing. My favorite example is that of atomic types such as [`AtomicI32`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/atomic/struct.AtomicI32.html): you can mutate them using a shared reference, because that is just what they do, but if you think of `&self` as an immutable thing you get a contradiction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `UdpSocket::send_to` just [uses `c::sendto` internally](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.75.0/library/std/src/sys_common/net.rs#L547-L561) the behavior is exactly the same.

The `*Socket` types don't need a mutable reference to do anything, because the OS is doing any required locking, so all of these types use a form of interior mutability to do their work, and that's a common theme amongst OS interfaces, `&File` for example [also implements `Read`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.File.html#impl-Read-for-%26File) despite most of the methods requiring an exclusive reference.